# Many buttons, one popup. How can i manage to make a content visible or hidden depended on the button value?

Tags: javascript, html, closures, comparison, store

I have many buttons and also one popup div which includes short or long content depended on value from a map.

Case 1: If content is hidden(windows.onload, it is hidden), if any button is clicked, the content should be visible then if same button is clicked, the content should be hidden again.

Case 2: If content is visible due to a clicked button, if any button(except same button like in case 1) is clicked, the content should not be hidden, keep being visible.

In the code below, i could manage to handle case 1 but not case 2. I think, i need to make a comparison function between first and last time called values of buttons but i cant find the way of storing first value so i cant make a comparison.

Should i use "JavaScript Closures" because i think that it may work.https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_closures5
if i should, is there any workaround? i prefer to use another method rather than to use Closures because i dont understand logic of "Closures" enough for now.

Thank you.

```js
function infoFunc(clicked_value) {
  let infoText = "";
  let control = "q1";

  for (let qvalue of questionDetails.keys()) {

    if (clicked_value == qvalue) {
      let y = questionDetails.get(qvalue);
      infoText = `<p>${y}</p>`;
      document.getElementById("questioninfoDiv").innerHTML = infoText;
    }
  }

  popupcontrolFunc(clicked_value, control);
}

/* Functions: " control of information popup" */

function popupcontrolFunc(clicked_value, control) {

  if (control == clicked_value) {
    popupTrueOrFalse();

  } else {
    popupTrue();
    control = clicked_value;
  }
}

function popupTrueOrFalse() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("questioninfoDiv");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function popupTrue() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("questioninfoDiv");
  popup.classList.toggle("show", true);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="questionInfoimg" value="${key}" onClick="infoFunc(this.value)"><img src="question-mark.svg" 
   alt="Info_Mark">
   </button>
```

edit: i guess, i need to make it more clear. Please check out the https://jsfiddle.net/GrayCollar/odnhgkpx/22/
Actually, i think, i need a algorithm and a way to use that algorithm like "js closures". i am not sure about "js closures", just try to explain what i need.

Comment: First of your HTML is invalid. You're missing a `>`  My other suggestion is to put w3schools on your ignore list.

Comment: Can you please create a  [mcve]?

Comment: When you set a global variable, it actually becomes part of the `window` object. So, you could use that.

Comment: What means *"which includes short or long content depended on value from a map"*?

Comment: HTML elements can have `data` fields, which look like this: `<button data-item="value"></element>`. They can be accessed using the `dataset` property of the element. In this example, you would access the `data-item` attribute with `element.dataset.item`, which you can also write to. Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Don't use inline `style` or `on*` attributes. CSS and JS should be in one place only, and that's their respective CSS or JS tags or files. Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @LastNameFirstName `</element>` ? You mean `</button>`. Also never use `button` without defining it's `type`

Comment: `let infoText = "";` is unnecessary.

Comment: What is `questionDetails.get` ?

Comment: Why don't you use `Object.keys(myObject).forEach()` ?

Comment: Store `document.getElementById("questioninfoDiv")` into a variable. If you reuse that elment often there's no need to go query the DOM for it  - inside every function.

Comment: why are you using a button? seems like a checkbox element would suit this better. Then just do element.checked for status

Comment: please click green square buttons to test cases.

Comment: Btw, I am new to programming and just started to learn html+css+js about 1.5 months ago so cant reply all questions for now but i will work on your recommendations. I would be appreciated for any recommendations but if we can focus on cases, may be better for now because the code is working but not properly. For now, i focus on making code work properly, getting result. Later, i can re-write the code based your recommendations or use that recommendations in my next small projects. Thank you, again.

Comment: @tstrand66 thank you,  i will try your "Checkbox" advice.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you for your advices but i will work on your advices which are about readability and performance(i guess?) later, i definetly put them in the pocket to use later.  Must i use `Object.keys(myObject).forEach()` ? dont my loops work properly except that cases?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need closures.

The `this` keyword will do the trick. According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this),

> When a function is used as an event handler, its this is set to the element on which the listener is placed (some browsers do not follow this convention for listeners added dynamically with methods other than `addEventListener()`).

This will not work in strict mode. In that case, you will have to pass an event object into the function, which looks like so.

```js
element.addEventListener(eventString, function(e){
        //e is the event object
});
```

This event object has a [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property, which is basically the element that the event is target to, which in this case is the button that is clicked. All put together, it looks like this:

```js
function eventHandler(e){
        //use e.currentTarget
}
element.addEventListener(eventString, eventHandler);
```